# Python dataclasses, correct way to default_factory a list of default dicts containing lists?

Tags: python

I'd like to accomplish an init of a list, containing default dicts, in turn containing lists.

What I have tried:

```py
@dataclass
class MyClass:
    self.b: int
    
    cache: list = field(default_factory=list) 

    def __post_init__(self):
        self.cache = [defaultdict(list) for _ in range(self.b)]
```

I'd appreciate help. Thank you.

Comment: can you provide some sample input?. It is not clear

Comment: An empty list of defaultdicts of lists is just an empty list.

Comment: And why is the type annotation `dict`? That's not any of the types you mentioned.

Comment: sorry, yes the type annotation is way off! See edit for what I've ended up doing, I basically just want to be able to go cache[i]['something'].append() without cache[i]['something'] actually being checked before hand

Answer (score 6):

> I basically just want to be able to go cache[i]['something'].append()

Something like the below

```
from dataclasses import dataclass,field
from collections import defaultdict

@dataclass
class MyClass:
    b: int
    cache: list = field(default_factory=list) 

    def __post_init__(self):
        self.cache = [defaultdict(list) for _ in range(self.b)]

mc: MyClass = MyClass(3)

mc.cache[1]['demo'].append('something')
print(mc)
```

output

```
MyClass(b=3, cache=[defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {}), defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'demo': ['something']}), defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {})])
```

Comment: Note that you could also use an [`InitVar`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#init-only-variables) here if you do don't want to explicitly set a `b` attribute, which I don't think you technically want here. So to do that, the only changes needed would be to define the field like `b: InitVar[int]`, and then the post init signature would become `def __post_init__(self, b: int):`

Comment: I can't see a difference between your suggestion and what I had? Except that I accidentally posted the dummy class with a `self.b` instead of just `b`.